# Trying to remove duplicate elements

Tags: java, set, hashset, duplicates

I'm messing around trying to learn to use HashSets to remove duplicate elements in my output but I'm running into some trouble.

My goal is to select a text file when the program is run and for it to display the words of the text file without duplicates, punctuation, or capital letters. All of it works fine except for removing the duplicates.

This is my first time using a Set like this. Any suggestions as to what I'm missing? Thanks!

Partial text file input for example: "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation, so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Lab7 {

    public interface OrderedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Iterable<T>
    {
        public void add(T element);
        public T removeFront();
        public T removeRear();
        public int size();
        public boolean isEmpty();
        public boolean contains(T element);
        public Iterator<T> iterator();
    }


    public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner scan = null;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");     
        int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            scan = new Scanner(file);
        }
        else
            return;
        int count = 0;

        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
         String[] noDuplicate = {scan.next().replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase()};
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(noDuplicate);

           set.addAll(list);

            count++;
    }
    scan.close();

    System.out.println(set);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(chooser.getName() + " has " + count + " words.");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output and actual output?

Comment: My desired output is to have my text file displayed without duplication, punctuation, or capitals. My actual output is that exactly except I still have duplicate words.

Comment: Do you care about order of the words? Meaning, do you care that they are outputted in the same order that they first appear in the text file?

Comment: Yes I do. I would like the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a `new` HashSet every time you read a word using the Scanner, so there is no chance for it to do de-duplication. You can fix it with the following steps.  Also, normal `HashSet` does not retain ordering.

1. Create the HashSet once, before the Scanner loop.
2. Use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), so that order is preserved in the same order that you added it.
3. Inside the loop, use `set.add(item);`. As the other answer mentions, you do not need to create a one-element list.

Adding the code for completeness.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    Scanner scan = null;
    scan = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
    int count = 0;

    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        String word = scan.next().replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase();
        set.add(word);
        count++;
    }
    scan.close();
    // System.out.println(set);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Input.txt  has " + count + " words.");

    // How do I print a set by myself?
    for (String word : set) {
        // Also remove commas
        System.out.println(word.replaceAll(",",""));
    }

}
```

Comment: I did exactly that (or so I thought) and I'm still getting the same output. Here's my code for in and around the loop.

Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

  while(scan.hasNext())
        {
    String[] noDuplicate = {scan.next().replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase()};
             List<String> list = Arrays.asList(noDuplicate);

            set.addAll(list);

             count++;
        }
        scan.close();
        
        System.out.println(set);

Comment: My bad. I edited it in my code originally posted. Not sure how to add code to comment.

Comment: @Bfrank, Please add sample input into your question as well.

Comment: @Bfrank, Show the partial contents of one file that you are trying to feed to your program.

Comment: @Bfrank You do realize that `count` will always increment, and does not show you the number of unique words, correct?

Comment: @merlin2011, I put in a piece of text I'm trying to input.

Comment: @Azar, yes I do realize that.

Comment: @merlin2011, I saw the problem and fixed it. All is well with the world now! Haha thank you.

Comment: One more thing to add. Silly question - How can I remove the "[]" at the beginning and end of text and remove the commas between words as well when running the program.

Comment: @Bfrank, What you are seeing is Java's way of printing a Set. If you want to print it yourself, you will have to iterate over it. The comma question is a separate question, which I'll address in my update.

Comment: @merlin2011, Ah thank you so much for all of the help. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        String noDuplicate = scan.next().replaceAll("[\\W]", "").toLowerCase();
        set.add(noDuplicate);
    }
scan.close();
System.out.println("The text has " + set.size() + " unique words.");
```

Your solution (Creating a one element array, converting that to a `List`, and converting *that* to a `HashSet`) is extremely inefficient, in addition to being incorrect. Just use the `String` you're originally working with, and add it to the `LinkedHashSet` (which will preserve ordering). At the end `set.size()` will show you the number of unique words in your sentence.